# Access chrome storage API from a javascript file listed in web_accessible_resources

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Is there a way to access the Chrome Extension APIs from a web_accessible_resources file?**

I'm trying to access the "chrome.storage.sync.get" function from a javascript file that is listed under 'web_accessible_resources' in my manifest file. The javascript file is executing successfully and works well for reading/writing DOM objects. It seems that I can't access the Chrome Extension APIs from this file though.

The file is injected into the webpage by my content script.

Comment: When a script is running as a `script` element in the web page, it's just a page script that can only access what a web page script can, it can't access extension storage. You can use messaging via DOM CustomEvent between this script and the content script.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks!